# Why findViewById() throws Null Exception?

Tags: android, findviewbyid

Why findViewById throws NULL Exception?Here is layout and sourcecode file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
...
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/usernameText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the source code in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      
    try{
        TextView text=(TextView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        text.setText(10);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("Log", e.getMessage()+"Error!"); // LogCat message

    }

}
```

However, `findViewById()`returns null, and I don't know even why. This Code is so simple.

Comment: does usernameText belongs to  activity_main ?

Comment: @huaxz1986 text.setText(10+"");and TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameText);

Comment: try callinng `findViewById(R.id.usernameText)` without MainActivity.this

Comment: @blackbelt:it belongs to activity_main .

Comment: Title says "throws null exception", question body says "returns null" and accepted answer implies no null at all. Even though you may have solved your problem, this is unlikely to help anyone else in its current form. Voting to close as "too localized".

Comment: @blackbelt:Sorry,that is my fault.I change the body now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
text.setText(10);
```

in this way you are looking for a `String` with `id = 10;` You should change in

```
 text.setText(String.valueOf(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code................

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        try{
            text.setText(String.valueOf(10));
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("Log", e.getMessage()+"Error!"); // LogCat message
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is that: setText(10) is not correct, it must be setText(String). So when i change it to setText(10+" "), it works right.